# How to add a text in a file with an argument in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add the text passed as an argument in powershell to config file. Below is the sample of the code. What I am expecting that below command will read the config file & search for parameter1 & when it find the parameter it will add the value (passed as an argument) after "="

```
(gc config.params) -replace "Parameter1 =", "$&` $1" | sc inifile.params
```

So the output supposed to be like:
Parameter1 = hostname

when the following command will be executed:
powershell.exe Untitled1.ps1 hostname

Please suggest.

Comment: Wow, `$&` in regex replacement string, how have I not seen that before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is not how arguments are passed to PowerShell scripts; they get an array `$args` or you specify parameter names. And the array does not have the script path as the first element.

So, for your code:

```
(gc config.params) -replace "Parameter1 =", "$&` $($args[0])" | sc inifile.params
```

or

```
param($text)

(gc config.params) -replace "Parameter1 =", "$&` $text" | sc inifile.params
```

Comment: I executed the first command and it gives me the below output:
Parameter1 = [0]

Comment: I put `"Parameter1 =" -replace "Parameter1 =", "$& $($args[0])"` in a script and run `.\test.ps1 hostname` and get `Parameter1 = hostname` ..  what exact code do you have? Did you definitely put the `$()` around the variable? Did you run it in a shell prompt where `$args` is nothing, or by putting it in a script?

Comment: My code is :
(gc inifile.params) -replace "NW_CI_Instance.ciVirtualHostname =", "$& $($args[0])" | sc inifile.params & i ran it with command
powershell.exe Untitled1.ps1 test